# Divisibility sequence resulting in limit with pi

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, limits, divisibility, pi

Consider the following sequence of operations :

> Start with a natural number $n$ and then round it up to the closest multiple of $n-1$ .Then round up this new number to the closest multiple of $n-2$ and so on until you round to a multiple of $1$ . Call this last number $f(n)$ .

For example for $n=11$ the sequence is :
$11,20,27,32,35,36,40,40,42,42,42$ and this means that $f(11)=42$

At first it seemed to me that this sequence is extremely hard to predict because we can't know how the multiples are distributed .

But to my amazement the following limit holds :

> Prove that: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{f(n)}=\pi$$

**What I found** :

- If $k \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ then after the $k$-th operation the number is $(k+1)(n-k)$ .

This is not hard to prove by induction on $k$ . As an example the sequence for $n=11$ can be seen as :
$$11,2 \cdot 10,3 \cdot 9,4 \cdot 8 ,5 \cdot 7 ,6 \cdot 6, \ldots $$

But after this we have $40=5 \cdot 8$ that breaks the pattern .I couldn't find any such patterns for $k>\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ and the sequence afterwards seems pretty arbitrary .

I am still amazed by how $\pi$ plays a role in this pure number theoretic question and I'd love to see a proof of the limit (or at least something new about the sequence ).

Thanks for everyone that can help me with this extraordinary problem .

Comment: How do you know that the limit is $\pi$ without a proof? What's the source of this problem?

Comment: It's from a book of recreational mathematics that unfortunately doesn't has a proof of it . The book is called : **A Passion for Mathematics: Numbers, Puzzles, Madness, Religion, and the Quest for Reality** by  Clifford A Pickover . This is an amazing book with a lot of nice things like this.

Comment: What I really mean is this : Start with $11$ . Then look at the closest multiple of $10$ bigger than it . This is $20$ . Now look at this number and   search for the closest bigger multiple of $9$ which is $27$ , then with a multiple of $8$ you get $32$ and so on until a multiple of $1$ which is $42$ so $f(11)=42$ . Hope you understand now.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002491

Comment: Wow, @Ivan! Nice detected. It seems it has to do with a product very slowly converging to $\pi$

Comment: Very nice find .I didn't thought of searching through oeis .I will look through that proof .Thanks a lot .

Comment: In the link provided by \Ivan Neretin ,click on the link : K.S. Brown, Rounding Up To PI.  Complete proof and additional comments.